# New line in code with no white space in output?

Tags: line-breaking, code

I would like to put my `\footnotes{}` on a separate line in code, to make code easier to maintain and read. But I don't want any whitespace in between the foot note, and the preceeding word in the output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make it this way:

```
word%
\footnote{footnote text}
more text
```

In other words set a percent sign directly after the word, where the footnote belongs to.
See also [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).

Comment: I do exactly the same, but the end of my footnote looks like this: `} %`.  This way I can use wrap the lines in emacs (e.g., `M-q`) and it won't put the 'more text' on the same line as the end of the footnote.

Comment: This works great...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I just solve that by:

```
\renewcommand\footnote{\nolinebreak \kern-1mm \LTRfootnote}
```

here:

- `\nolinebreak` allows me to prevent footnote break at the end of
  lines
- `\kern-1mm` removes the white space which is produced by the
  new-line.

*here I just used `\LTRfootnote` for my own purpose. you can use your own command*

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `-1mm` isn't necessarily the width of the space that is to be ignored.  That could be more or less, depending on the actual text content of the line.  In most cases, it probably won't make much difference, but if the spaces in the line are particularly shrunk, the footnote number could conceivably overprint the previous character.  Using `\unskip` and omitting the `\nolinebreak` should work more dependably.